# Upload resources to GeoNetwork filestore via CSW / API

Tags: api, geonetwork, csw

I am exploring GeoNetwork to get if it is suitable for my purpose.

I need to use a script to upload several metadata with a file JSON associated. Is there any chance to use CSW / API to upload the files to the filestore available in the GUI (https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/en/user-guide/associating-resources/using-filestore.html) ?

Comment: When you say with a JSON file associated, what do you mean?  Do you mean the metadata to be uploaded is JSON, or do you mean that the data being described by the metadata is JSON? or something else, sorry it isn't clear.

Comment: I mean the data being described by the metadata is JSON

Answer (score 1):

You'd need two calls, one to the CSW-T service to create the metadata record and other to store the JSON file in the filestore using the GeoNetwork API:
`POST /{portal}/api/0.1/records/{metadataUuid}/attachments`

You can check the parameters here https://vanilla.geocat.net/geonetwork/doc/api/index.html#/records/putResourceFromFile

Comment: Thank you, didnt notice that API!

Comment: EDIT: I tried the API directly from Swagger and through Postman. In both the cases, I faced with Error 403 Forbidden. 
I used my user and pwd on Swagger,
I used my user and pwd as basic auth on Postman. How can I authenticate this API?

Comment: That's probably caused because GN is not receiving the right XSRF token. Check the API guide at https://www.geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/en/api/the-geonetwork-api.html